# Need Firebase Database behaviour clarification when saving and reading offline

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

I need a clarification on firebase offline capabilities.

I understand that if I enable the offline mode,  queries still be executed offline,  and saves will be executed when back online.

Now, I am not sure what happens in the following scenario:

1) Read from path '/companies/'
let's say it returns 2 keys,  with data inside each one

```
/companies/1111111/....
/companies/2222222/....
```

2) now I save a new company in the following path . (remember that I am offline)

```
/companies/3333333/....
```

3) I return to the previous query and I Read from path '/companies/'

it will return 2 keys or 3 keys ? 
What I mean is that if the save happened locally and its just waiting to sync or since its not executed yet,  its not going to be returned in the query?

Answer (score 2):

Any writes that you perform at any time (either online or offline) are immediately reflected in all subsequent queries (either online or offline).

So, in your example, it will return three keys.  You should be able to observe this pretty easily by cutting network access to your emulator or device during testing.

Comment: There are actually some subtleties in this behavior, so it depends on the exact API calls you make. So: if you have something unexpected, post a question with the [minimal code that reproduces the behavior and we'll have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).